# Combining items of list with same beginning

Tags: python

I need to do a loop to run through a list and join all values with a certain string to the preceding value. I have the following, which only partially gets the job done.

```
thing = ["abc","bde","bdf","bdg","bei"]

for i in thing:
    if "bd" in i:
         value = thing.index(i)
         thing[value-1]=thing[value-1]+thing[value]
         del thing[value]

print thing
```

When this is put in, I get:

```
['abcbde', 'bdfbdg', 'bei']
```

The desired result is:

```
['abcbdebdfbdg', 'bei']
```

edit: fixed indentation

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to SO! Could you please fix the indentation in your code example? As it stands, it is invalid Python code and the indentation _may_ have a role to play in resolving your issue.

Comment: also iterating on a list while changing elements may cause trouble.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake while writing the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, I would not recommend changing `thing` as you iterate through it because it may have unintended consequences. Try this:

```
thing=['abc', 'bde', 'bdf', 'bdg', 'bei']
output=[thing[0]] # initiate output to ['abc']
for i in thing[1:]: #['bde', 'bdf', 'bdg', 'bei']
    if 'bd' in i: 
        output[-1]=output[-1]+i
    else: 
        output.append(i)

print(output)
#['abcbdebdfbdg', 'bei']
```

Start iterating from `'bde'` so that you have an element in `output` to accumulate on. Then use the `[-1]` splice to get the last element of `output` and append if `'bd'` is in the current iteration.

If you did want to empty `thing` then I would recommend using the list `.pop` method. That way at the end of your loop, `thing=[]`.